# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$. Prove there exist a subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ such that $\lim a_{n_i} = \lim_n \inf a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb R$. Prove there exist a subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ such that $\lim a_{n_i} = \lim_n \inf a_n$

By definition $\lim_n \inf a_n = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} [\inf \{a_n\}_{n=k}^{\infty}$].

However $\inf \{a_n\}_{n=k}^{\infty}$ may not be an element of $\{a_n\}$, but we do know that some subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converge to this number.

How can I utilize this to construct the subsequence that converge to $\lim_n \inf a_n$ ?

Comment: Google "Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every $k$, let $b_k = \inf\limits_{k \leqslant n} a_n$. You know that $(b_k)$ is monotonically nondecreasing and converges to $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$. Also, by definition of $\inf$, for every $k$ there is an index $n_k \geqslant k$ with $b_k \leqslant a_{n_k} < b_k + 2^{-k}$. You can use that fact to construct a subsequence of $(a_n)$ converging to $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$.

Comment: Taking the limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$ using your inequility doesn't that give a contradiction ?

Comment: No, why do you think it would give a contradiction? The inequality gives you the existence of arbitrarily large $n$ with $a_n < \liminf a_n + \varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$. Consider a sequence $\varepsilon_m \searrow 0$, and choose an increasing $n_m$ with $a_{n_m} < \liminf a_n + \varepsilon_m$. Verify that that subsequence converges to $\liminf a_n$.